# Node.js, For loop

Tags: node.js

in node.js I am using for loop on server.js but it is not working and cause error

```
var myEasyrtcApp = function(err, appObj) {
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
appObj.createRoom("room" + i ,null,function(err, roomObj){});
};
}
```

Please advice how can I use for loop to call appObj.createRoom several time to open different conference room

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you almost not give any information... Asuming the last function is a Callback you need to make a Recursive "Loop" something like:
http://pastebin.com/LrKqLgyV

And to use it you can do this:
http://pastebin.com/L1bZZis0

To learn more about this, just google "recursive functions". (I can't post more than 2 links XD)

Hope It works for you ;)